# For loop - problem with indents. Needs rearranging

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Following script is supposed to get me data from different pages.

It's difficult to add the data as the URL is static and non-changing. The table I'm scraping is a pop-up.

URL: https://www.formularylookup.com/

Here's some data and the page changer(does not incl. data from other pages):

```
html = '<div class="k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" id="lookupDetailsGrid" style="height: 75%;"><div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 5px;"><div class="k-grid-header-wrap"><table role="grid"><colgroup><col class="k-hierarchy-col"/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><thead role="rowgroup"><tr role="row"><th class="k-hierarchy-cell k-header"> </th><th class="col-plan k-header" data-field="PlanName" data-index="0" data-title="Plan" id="bbabe5e5-37a9-4e77-a67d-753ebd33ef7a" role="columnheader" rowspan="1">Plan</th><th class="col-status k-header" data-field="UnifiedTierShortName" data-index="1" data-title="Status" id="4d4d4a85-131c-4372-8bc3-5c525a49efda" role="columnheader" rowspan="1">Status</th><th class="col-raw-status k-header" data-field="DrugListTierName" data-index="2" data-title="Raw Status" id="1f9a4790-b954-40fa-aded-8a84b2cc5e34" role="columnheader" rowspan="1">Raw Status</th><th class="col-restrictions k-header" data-field="Restrictions" data-index="3" data-title="Restrictions" id="6c4c0c52-5c36-4191-9412-134b0c2c9f5a" role="columnheader" rowspan="1">Restrictions</th><th class="col-alternatives k-header" data-field="CoveredAlternatives" data-index="4" data-title="Covered Alternatives" id="8ab600f2-bdc6-4da2-8f5c-b4e932bdaa4c" role="columnheader" rowspan="1">Covered Alternatives</th></tr></thead></table></div></div><div class="k-grid-content" style="height: 476px;"><table class="k-selectable" data-role="selectable" role="treegrid" style="height: auto;"><colgroup><col class="k-hierarchy-col"/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><tbody role="rowgroup"><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="9c23ff5f-4fcc-4d1d-8d6a-2d56893e046e" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Tropicana Atlantic City</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63890" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="c964375c-83e7-41b0-af5f-84e4c26649be" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">WCA Hospital</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63891" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="c3cf9b00-1515-41d9-a6a5-c2ab0a72b5a3" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Tropicana Entertainment Inc</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63892" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="8b7dbae9-88db-426d-957a-09e35fcfcc54" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Riverside Health Care</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63893" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="15f8ec55-d3b2-4f63-b0c9-bf3105b19bad" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Transylvania University</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63894" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="32d72970-aeea-43e8-9c6b-18edbc00bfea" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">WestPoint Home</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63895" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="13442ffb-67ef-4f90-8108-5b2cff58281c" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">CVR Partners</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63896" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="b449ce4a-c522-4800-a8b6-aca35ef7a7c0" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">CVR Energy</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63897" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="94aa0a86-cac9-4a74-a413-d1cee3b9aff8" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Kentucky Teachers Retirement System</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="63898" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="7be626dd-3c80-45ea-b76f-46f6b662f383" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">SEIU Local 32BJ District 36 Benefits Fund</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="64379" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="ec9245d6-88d3-4a37-8346-221320a930bd" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Bass Pro Shops</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="64574" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="18c672c0-42f3-4f77-93b7-4b40b85169f8" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Laborers Union Local 872</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="64575" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="630a2c44-4256-47f3-a1c7-d43635af1b30" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Ironworkers District Council of Tennessee Valley &amp; Vicinity</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="64576" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="3fb4e1b8-d1b4-487e-9348-1ed456e360df" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Teamsters Local 830</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="65073" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="b785e533-e7f6-45fc-83a7-275f3cd4001e" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">UA Local 74</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="65079" mmit_isformulary="false">120 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="5460f5b9-5882-45fc-b40b-6125084a51ad" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">1199SEIU Home Care Industry Benefit</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="3201" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="a2bf1ccb-66ae-43b8-a59a-8d19e5f79c9b" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">United Federation of Teachers (UFT)</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="15354" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="92710963-d8a7-4177-85b6-703437893e9d" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Medical University of South Carolina</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="15375" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="3fa555a5-f1ac-4b8c-aa45-45012275959c" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">University of South Carolina by BlueChoice</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="61594" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="e51abae1-36b3-423c-a95b-7c6b783f43d7" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">School Employees Retirement System of Ohio (SERS)</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="17026" mmit_isformulary="false">58 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="efe3a535-661b-4c29-9458-079db9151209" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Ohio Teachers Retirement System (STRS)</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="17027" mmit_isformulary="false">58 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="39dc9ebd-bee8-4209-a4b7-dba8b7e58349" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Ohio PERS Non-Medicare Plan</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="60209" mmit_isformulary="false">58 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="1371938b-8242-4ad2-b7e7-6ccee0fabdb3" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Perdue Farms</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="62392" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr><tr class="k-alt k-master-row" data-uid="aba9a103-a22f-4d75-bec5-ae6e619029da" role="row"><td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a class="" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></td><td class="col-plan" role="gridcell">Montana State Fund Workers Comp</td><td class="col-status icon-status icon-status-not-covered" role="gridcell">Not Covered</td><td class="col-raw-status" role="gridcell">Not reimbursed</td><td class="col-restrictions" role="gridcell"></td><td class="col-alternatives" role="gridcell"><div class="HasAlternativesPopUp" mmit_id="65760" mmit_isformulary="false">121 </div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget k-floatwrap" data-role="pager"><a class="k-link k-pager-nav k-pager-first" data-page="1" href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Go to the first page"><span class="k-icon k-i-seek-w">Go to the first page</span></a><a class="k-link k-pager-nav" data-page="28" href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Go to the previous page"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-w">Go to the previous page</span></a><ul class="k-pager-numbers k-reset"><li class="k-current-page"><span class="k-link k-pager-nav">29</span></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="20" href="#" tabindex="-1" title="More pages">...</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="21" href="#" tabindex="-1">21</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="22" href="#" tabindex="-1">22</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="23" href="#" tabindex="-1">23</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="24" href="#" tabindex="-1">24</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="25" href="#" tabindex="-1">25</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="26" href="#" tabindex="-1">26</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="27" href="#" tabindex="-1">27</a></li><li><a class="k-link" data-page="28" href="#" tabindex="-1">28</a></li><li><span class="k-state-selected">29</span></li></ul><a class="k-link k-pager-nav k-state-disabled" data-page="29" href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Go to the next page"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e">Go to the next page</span></a><a class="k-link k-pager-nav k-pager-last k-state-disabled" data-page="29" href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Go to the last page"><span class="k-icon k-i-seek-e">Go to the last page</span></a><span class="k-pager-info k-label">1401 - 1424 of 1424 items</span></div></div>'
```

**Current function:**
So far the code gets a single item from page 1 appends to total, clicks next page button (to page 2), gets the second item from page 1 appends to total, clicks next page (page 3), gets third item from page 1 appends to total, click next page (page 4) etc.

**Desired function:**
What it should do is scrape all items on page 1 and append to total, click next page, scrape all new items on page 2 and append to total, click next page, etc.

I use a combination of BS4 and Selenium.

```py
        html = self.browser.page_source
        total = [] 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

        for e in soup.find_all("div", {"id":"lookupDetailsGrid"}):
            #max_page gets me the total number of pages to go through (27 pages)
            max_page = e.find("a", {"title":"Go to the last page"})["data-page"]

            for page in range(1,int(max_page)):

                for detail_grid in e.find_all("tr", {"class":"k-master-row"}):

                    pharm = detail_grid.find("td", {"class":"col-plan"}).text
                    print(pharm)
                    data = {"Plan": pharm}
                    total.append(data)

                    time.sleep(5)

                    #Clicks next page button
                    self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lookupDetailsGrid"]/div[3]/a[3]').click()

        df = pd.DataFrame(total)
        print(df)
```

The result of this is

```
CVS Caremark Performance Standard Control w/Advanced Specialty Control
CVS Caremark Performance Standard Opt-Out w/ Advanced Specialty Control 
CVS Caremark Advanced Control Formulary
CVS Caremark Performance Standard Control
AT&T
```

Which are the first 5 results of page 1. There are 50 in total per page.

**Question:**
How should I arrange the indents?

**Desired output:** 
50 items per page, for a total of 1330 items in total in 27 pages.

Latest update:

```
html = self.browser.page_source
total = [] 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    for grid in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"popup k-window-content k-content"}):

        for e in grid.find_all("div", {"id":"lookupDetailsGrid"}):
            max_page = e.find("a", {"title":"Go to the last page"})["data-page"]

            for b in range(1, int(max_page)):    
                self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lookupDetailsGrid"]/div[3]/a[3]').click()
                print("page_clicked")
                time.sleep(2)

                for detail_grid in e.find_all("tr", {"class":"k-master-row"}):
                    pharm = detail_grid.find("td", {"class":"col-plan"}).text

                    data = {"Plan": pharm}
                    total.append(data)
                    print(pharm)
```

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: Its required login I believe.

Comment: it is yes. I can send you a PM if you're interested. I cannot share it in public, unfortunately.

Comment: Once you log in, you have to click on of the Payers, which will give you the pop-up with an overview over Plans for the payer, the first payer being "CVS Caremark RX" . I'm trying to scrape the plans for top 10 payers.

Comment: Where does come from `grid` and `detail_grid`? Also why aren't you using `html`? Looks like you edited your code. Anyway it's pretty easy, you click on the next page button but never update any of those variables. You need to put a little something after `for page in range(1,int(max_page)):`

Comment: The application is somehow blocking from my workplace.Will give it try once I reach home.Sorry I have to disappoint you.

Comment: No worries. Still playing around with it myself. I just don't understand why it keep giving me the same information even when page is changed. I hope you can help later.

Comment: Posted an updated version of the code. Loops through every page, but gives me same result every time. Like it doesn't recognize that the page is changed. How is that possible